# Atomic access of enums in Qt

Tags: qt, atomic

So I am trying to do something like this

```
enum MyEnum
{
    A =0,
    B,
    C
};

QAtomicInteger< MyEnum > myVariable;
```

I get an error

`C2338: template parameter is not an integral type`

Is there a way to do this without resorting to casting things back and forth to `int`?   That makes for ugly code.

The thrust of this is multi-threading.  One thread writes to the variable, another reads from it.

The way I used to do such things is declare as

```
volatile MyEnum myVariable.
```

but I understand that is considered non-portable.

Comment: Enum values are always read-only. Is there any sense of making them atomic?

Comment: @jaskmar  Thread 1 writes to myVariable, Thread 2 reads from myVariable

Comment: I see. Try `std::atomic` OR `enum class MyEnum : int {/*...*/}`.

Comment: A typed enum will not work either. An std atomic however would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QAtomicInteger` is not supposed to work with enums. Just use `std::atomic<MyEnum>` from standard library (you need to enable `C++11` or later).

Comment: This does work on the current story being done, but it is a bit of a disappointment, as `QAtomicInteger` seems targeted with the same sort of goal that `std::atomic` is, so there really is no good reason why is shouldn't work.  `std::atomic` shows it is possible..  We do have other projects that still use Qt with MSVS2010, and now we won't have the option to reuse the code on those projects as MSVS2010 is not C++11

Comment: @infixed MSVC2017 does not support 100% C++11 neither. Using MS compiler with "reuse the code" on your mind is always a sort of insanity. But on Windows you don't have much choice.

Answer (score 0):

`volatile` has nothing to do with atomicity.

There is no such thing as "atomic access of enums". Enums are a compile time construct, atomic access is a runtime thing.

An enum is not an integer, even if its values essentially are. So the following code will work:

```
  QAtomicInt myVar;
  myVar.store(A);
```

You may also notice that this code will not compile:

```
  MyEnum ev = 0; // invalid conversion
```

Comment: No, voltille has to do with optimization.  So if one thread has a write to `myVariable`, and then a blocking `emit signal()` to another thread (that writes to `myVariable`), followed by a read from MyVariable, the optimizer will not assume that `myVariable` not been altered and optimize away the read.

Comment: @infixed - `volatile` is for when a variable might be changed from outside the code, for example by a hardware interrupt or something like that. It has **nothing** to do with multi-threading whatsoever. And it will not in any way prevent potential race conditions. `volatile` will remove certain optimizations, but access is **not atomic**. The two concepts are fundamentally different things.

Comment: `volatile` indeed makes variable atomic but only with Visual C++ compilers! It has nothing to do with C++ standards.

Comment: So you don't consider another thread as 'outside the code' of one thread?  Yes its not thread safe if underplaying operations are not atomic (like interruptible multibyte operations) .   But an implementation of`enum` is rarely that.  As I said I am trying to avoid it.

Comment: No I don't. It is a common misconception that `volatile` is about multithreading. It is not. It is for interfacing with hardware, when there is possibility that a value might be changed from outside the process, for example, by a hardware interrupt. It is about NOT keeping variables in registers, but always reading from and writing to memory, so that the data can be in sync with the hardware interface that is accessing it.

Comment: As a guy who has coded embedded systems for decades I tell you that `volatile` is very important for coding interrupt service routines, which while often are connected with hardware, usually have to read and write shared memory also used by the background process.  Background and Foreground may not be exactly multi-threading, but they face similar challenges.   if I have `myVariable = A`; emit blockingsignal(); if ( myVariable == A ) { ...}` it is very likely that the optimizer if going to optimize `myVariable ==  A` to `true` absent a `volatile`.

Comment: Except that during a hardware interrupt the client code is... well, interrupted, it does not execute until the interrupt handler is finished. So there is no room for a race condition, unlike with multithreading.

Comment: @dtech Sure there can be race conditions.  that why there are mitigations like the background disabling interrupts around critical sections.  Comes up in stuff like queuing data all the time in embedded systems